# run exe with parameters silently from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters, command-prompt, executable

I want to execute an *executable* along with it's parameters from a *Batch file* silently without printing anything on the console from the executable and the executable shouldn't be executed from another console(*it shouldn't open another command-prompt* to execute). For that I tried with ***start*** command as following and couldn't execute it.

```
start "C:\myApp.exe -mode='a' -inputFilePath='%filePath%'" -i silent
```

Where *%filePath%* is a variable and *-mode*,*-inputFilePath* are the arguments to my executable.

Please correct me for anything wrong in above statement and help me out in this. Thanks!

Comment: Try `start "title" "C:\myApp.exe" -mode="a" -inputFilePath="%filePath%" -i silent`. The first quoted string in the parameters is taken as the window title (e.g. for a console window). It can be empty `""`, but for clarity here I've made it `"title"`. Whether single quotes are supported for quoting is up to the application (i.e. "myApp.exe"), but generally single quotes are just literal characters in Windows, so I switched to using double quotes. Using double quotes also escapes special characters in CMD, except for `%`.

Comment: thanks @eryksun, but this opened another command-prompt while running the executable file, please suggest me a way to avoid printing the executable output in Batch file execution prompt or in a separate command-prompt window

Comment: But this much worked, right? It's important to step into a problem like this in layers instead of trying to solve it all in one pass.

Comment: Why is the command `start` used to run the executable as a separate process parallel to `cmd.exe` processing the batch file? Use `"C:\myApp.exe" -mode=a -inputFilePath="%filePath%" -i silent >nul 2>&1` and the executable is executed by `cmd.exe` without opening one more console window and suppressing all output to the handles __STDOUT__ and __STDERR__ by redirecting them to device __NUL__. Once the executable finished, `cmd.exe` continues processing the batch file.

Comment: @Mofi, in general I would add `<nul` as well to redirect stdin in case the program reads input. And if we don't need to wait and set the return code as `%errorlevel%`, I would use `start` with the `/B` option to prevent allocating a new console: `start "" /B "C:\myApp.exe" -mode="a" -inputFilePath="%filePath%" -i silent <nul >nul 2>&1`

Comment: If the program manually accesses the special files "CONIN$" and "CONOUT$", for the console's input and screen buffer, redirecting the standard handles won't help. We'd need a way to pass the creation flag `DETACHED_PROCESS` (8) to run it without a console at all, but CMD doesn't support this. It's possible if you can use another language such as Python.

Answer (score 2):

From your batch file, just execute the following:

```
C:\myApp.exe -mode='a' -inputFilePath='%filePath%' >NUL
```

the >NUL redirects the output to nothing for that command.